# Linux - Creating Virtual Audio Device

Tags: linux, audio, alsa

My question here is rather simple. How does one create a purely virtual audio device in ALSA that would be capable of:

1. being used as an audio output destination,
2. being used as an audio input source, outputting whatever has been sent to it.

What I'm essentially trying to achieve is outputting sound to this device, and using that device as a mic in another application (like Skype, for example), which allows me to play sounds and music in skype or whatever else that would be.

Information on this is really obscure, and search results show mostly irrelevant things, like splitting device outputs or something like that. I really have no idea where and what to look for now, so any help would be incredibly appreciated.

Comment: just load `snd-aloop`

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted - though it took me some time to figure it out properly.

Comment: @CL. You should post your comment as an answer, thus marking the question as solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To load the loopback module:

```
$ modprobe snd-aloop
```

Comment: The reason for the error: "Body must be at least 30 characters...". The error is above **and** to the right side in my browser.

Comment: $ modprobe snd-aloop  # for newbs

UI: ...Looks like they fixed it :-)